# Selenium WebDriver Java - POM - console results point to an element not used in the test case

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, pom.xml

Ran into an issue when the test cases fail and the console output says an element cannot be located, however, this element was not even used in the test case.
I am utilizing page object model pattern.
Does it have something to do with the order of execution of the elements of the class?

The test case:

```
public class FilterResultTestCaseActiveStudentsOnly {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println(" enter username ");
    Login.userName.sendKeys(Account.loginElenaB);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println(" enter password ");
    Login.password.sendKeys(Account.pswdElenaB);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println(" click login btn ");
    Login.loginButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println("click on Students page ");
    NavBar.studentsPage.click();
    Thread.sleep(6000);

    System.out.println("click on Filter Results Dropdown ");
    FiltersResultDropdown.clickOnFilterResultsDropdown.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println("select Active Students only radiobutton ");
    FiltersResultDropdown.activeStudentsOnlyFilterResultsDropdown.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println("click on Apply Filters Results Dropdown ");
    FiltersResultDropdown.applyFilterButtonFilterResultsDropdown.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

     StudentsPage.studentLinkClickStudentsPage.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);


     String activeStudentsOnlyText = GetTextForAsserts.getStatusActiveText.getText();

    try{
        Assert.assertEquals("STATUS: Active", activeStudentsOnlyText);
        System.out.println("The student is active");
    } catch(AssertionError e){  //What if there are not students filtered?  ToDo!
        System.out.println("The student not found");
        ;
        throw e;
    }
```

For asserts, I've created a class where I located necessary elements:
The class:

```
public class GetTextForAsserts {

    WebDriverSettings driver;

   public static WebElement getLetterOneText = WebDriverSettings.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"studentLetters\"]/tr[5]/td[4]"));

    public static WebElement getChronicLetterText = WebDriverSettings.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"studentLetters\"]/tr[4]/td[4]"));

    public static WebElement getStatusActiveText = WebDriverSettings.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"studentOverview\"]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]")); etc.

}
```

So, what it does - the test case fails, and the console says getLetterOneText cannot be located (or some another element), but it was not even used in the test case.
The Xpaths for all the elements are correct (even for the 'unlocated' ones), double checked multiple times.
To not fail the test case, I have to comment out the 'unlocated' element it points to, but it is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetTextForAsserts` class scrapes the page for all three elements, including `getLetterOneText`. So when you instantiate that class, it scrapes the page whether it's used or not.

A better practice is to have your variables store the locators, `By` class, instead of storing the elements. That way you can call a method that uses the locator to scrape the page when needed.

You should spend some time looking at page object model tutorials and references to learn more standard ways of doing things like this. Also you should spend some time learning how to debug your own programs. If you stepped through your code, you would have seen those lines execute and known what the issue was.